# Oracle 12c - How to GROUP and ORDER BY this query

Tags: sql, oracle

The following query is complaing on GROUP BY and ORDER BY expressions - Please help me rectify it - Thanks

    `SELECT
       a.FirstName|| ' ' ||a.LastName AS "Name", 
       ROUND(SUM((b.UnitPrice - b.Discount) * b.Quantity)/100000) AS "Sales" 
    FROM 
       Employees a, Order_Details b, Orders c 
    WHERE 
       a.EmployeeID = c.EmployeeID AND 
       b.OrderID = c.OrderID 
    GROUP BY 1 
    ORDER BY 2 DESC 
    FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;`

Here is the error :

```
a.FirstName|| ' ' ||a.LastName AS "Name",
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`
```

Regards
Tonya

Comment: you cannot specify column number in group by in oracle, only the column/expression itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
SELECT    a.FirstName|| ' ' ||a.LastName AS "Name",    
    ROUND(SUM((b.UnitPrice - b.Discount) * b.Quantity)/100000) AS
    "Sales"    
FROM     
    Employees a, Order_Details b, Orders c  
WHERE    
    a.EmployeeID = c.EmployeeID AND     
    b.OrderID = c.OrderID  
GROUP BY
    a.FirstName, a.LastName 
ORDER BY 
    2 DESC  
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.FirstName || ' ' || a.LastName AS "Name", 
       ROUND(SUM((b.UnitPrice - b.Discount) * b.Quantity)/100000) AS "Sales" 
  FROM Employees a, Order_Details b, Orders c 
 WHERE a.EmployeeID = c.EmployeeID
   AND b.OrderID = c.OrderID 
GROUP BY a.FirstName || ' ' || a.LastName
ORDER BY 2 DESC 
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Unlike the `ORDER BY` clause, you cannot use your `AS` column names or column position numbers. If the grouping column is an expression, then you must use that expression in the `GROUP BY` clause i.e. `a.FirstName || ' ' || a.LastName`.  `SUM` is the aggregate function that will be applied to this group even if it is a messy expression like this one is.